# laravel push queued jobs from different codebase

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, beanstalkd, laravel-queue

I'm trying to trigger Jobs from other codebase

MyCommand Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use App\Jobs\MyJob;


class EncodeTvVideos extends Command
{
    use DispatchesJobs;

    protected $signature = 'command:my';

    protected $description = '';

    public function handle()
    {
        $job = (new MyJob($this->argument()))
            ->onConnection('beanstalkd')
            ->onQueue('cron-default'));

        $this->dispatch($job);
    }
}
```

And MyJob Class:

```
<?php namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MyJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $payload;

    public function __construct($payload = null)
    {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        echo "Job processed here";
        $this->job->delete();
    }
}
```

I'm listen my queue by using queue:listen command like

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=cron-default
```

If i run command (inside some codebase) command:my i'm getting payload like this any processed successfully.

```
{
    "job":"Illuminate\\\\Queue\\\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
    "data":{
        "command":"O:29:\\"Acme\\Jobs\\FooJob\\":4:{s:11:\\"fooBar\\";s:7:\\"abc-123\\";s:5:\\"queue\\";N;s:5:\\"delay\\";N;s:6:\\"\\u0000*\\u0000job\\";N;}"
    }
}
```

Now my problem is i need to trigger this Job or command from other codebase is there any way?

I don't have domain name for the (commands/workers project) or else i could try create one route it will trigger command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the help this [ref](http://masnun.com/2015/05/24/using-laravel-queues-standalone-outside-laravel.html)

By using these packages "illuminate/queue": "5.2.*", "pda/pheanstalk": "~3.0", "illuminate/encryption": "5.2.*"

I'm able to push plain payload to the given tube like this

```
use Illuminate\Queue\Capsule\Manager as Queue;

$queue = new Queue;


// Some drivers need it
$queue->getContainer()->bind('encrypter', function() {
    return new Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter('foobar');
});

$queue->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'queue' => 'default',
], 'default');

$queue->push('App\Jobs\MyJob@process', ['data'=> 'something']);
```

//First parameter complete path of the JobClass in other codebase
//Second parameter any parameter to the Job.

Minor modification in my Job to handle both commands, and plain payload

```
<?php namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MyJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $payload;

    public function __construct($payload = null)
    {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        echo "Job processed here";
        $this->job->delete();
    }

   public function process($job, $payload)
    {
        echo "Job processed from plain payload";
        $job->delete();
    }
}
```